# Which header is served

Tags: child-theme, custom-header

I am using theme (Knowledgedesk) that includes a header.php in its child theme's directory. However the changes I make by editing header.php are not visibles.
It cannot be the cache, I [already checked](https://codex.wordpress.org/I_Make_Changes_and_Nothing_Happens) (and editing style.css works fine). 
Then, is there a way to determine which header.php is loaded (using browser network tab, access.log, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by using a plugin: [which template file](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/which-template-file/).